# Retrieving data from list in console app

Tags: c#, list

I'm writing a console application that can be used by teachers to save and retrieve data about a student.

I want to retrieve elements from the lists of `studentInfoName` and `studentInfoClassAndNumber` - so that the user can enter the name of the student and get all the other informations, like middle name, last name, class and number.

I tried using a `foreach` loop but it doesn't seem to work.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DrawStarLine();
            DrawTitle();
            DrawMenu();
            int answer = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            if (answer == 1)
            {

                Console.WriteLine("Enter information about a student");
                List<string> studentInfoName = new List<string>();
                Console.Write("Name: ");
                studentInfoName.Add(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.Write("Middle name: ");
                studentInfoName.Add(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.Write("Last name: ");
                studentInfoName.Add(Console.ReadLine());
                List<int> studentInfoClassAndNumber = new List<int>();
                Console.Write("Class ");
                studentInfoClassAndNumber.Add(int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()));
                Console.Write("Number ");
                studentInfoClassAndNumber.Add(int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()));
            }
            else if (answer == 2)
            {

                Console.WriteLine("Enter the name of the student that you want to retrieve information about");
              ?????????????????????????????????????????????????
            }
            else
            {
                ErrorMessage();
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        private static void ErrorMessage()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Typing error, press key to continue.");
        }
        private static void DrawStarLine()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("************************");
        }
        private static void DrawTitle()
        {
            DrawStarLine();
            Console.WriteLine("+++ Student Information Database +++");
            DrawStarLine();
        }
        private static void DrawMenu()
        {
            DrawStarLine();
            Console.WriteLine(" 1. Enter information about a student.");
            Console.WriteLine(" 2. Retrieve information about a student available in the program");
            Console.WriteLine(" 3. Exit from the program");
            DrawStarLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Make your choice: type 1, 2, or 3 for exit");
            DrawStarLine();
        }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Where is the list you want to retrieve elements from? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to retrieve elements from the lists studentInfoName and studentInfoClassAndNumber.

Comment: I want the user to enter the name of the student and get all the other information, like middle name, last name, class and number :)

Comment: Added further explanation from comments and edited for readability

Answer (score 0):

You have to initialize studentInfoClassAndNumber and studentInfoName outside the if:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DrawStarLine();
        DrawTitle();
        DrawMenu();

        List<int> studentInfoClassAndNumber = new List<int>();
        List<string> studentInfoName = new List<string>();

        int answer = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        if (answer == 1)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("Enter information about a student");

            Console.Write("Name: ");
            studentInfoName.Add(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("Middle name: ");
            studentInfoName.Add(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("Last name: ");
            studentInfoName.Add(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.Write("Class ");
            studentInfoClassAndNumber.Add(int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()));
            Console.Write("Number ");
            studentInfoClassAndNumber.Add(int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()));
        }
        else if (answer == 2)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("Enter the name of the student that you want to retrieve information about");
          ?????????????????????????????????????????????????
        }
        else
        {
            ErrorMessage();
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring your lists as local variables inside the if statement so that is their scope. When you leave that if statement, you leave that scope and you no longer have access to the variables you declared inside it. Try this instead:

```
var studentInfoName = new List<string>();
var studentInfoClassAndNumber = new List<int>();
if (answer == 1)
            {

                Console.WriteLine("Enter information about a student");
                Console.Write("Name: ");
                studentInfoName.Add(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.Write("Middle name: ");
                studentInfoName.Add(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.Write("Last name: ");
                studentInfoName.Add(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.Write("Class ");
                studentInfoClassAndNumber.Add(int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()));
                Console.Write("Number ");
                studentInfoClassAndNumber.Add(int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()));
            }
```

Now in your else you can do something like this:

```
foreach(string s in studentInfoName){
...
}
```

Some things to note, I use var instead of explicitly declaring the type on the left side of the evaluation as it saves line space and follows proper coding standard (though not entirely necessary).

I would also suggest renaming studentInfoName to studentName as it is just as clear and shorter.

Another suggestion is if you plan on using these variables outside of that specific function, create a property. Properties are written inside the class but outside of any methods and follow this format:

```
private Type _variableName;

public Type VariableName
{
get{ return _variableName;}
set{_variableName = value;}
}
```

The benefit to the property is that other classes can access the variables if they have an instance of this class. Also they are necesarry for databinding if you ever decide to create a gui with xaml. VS has a code snippet propfull (tab,tab) that will autogenerate most of the property code for you, or prop (tab,tab) that will autogenrate the property without the backing field (the private variable)

Comment: Error 1 A local variable named 'studentName' cannot be declared in this scope because it would give a different meaning to 'studentName', which is already used in a 'parent or current' scope to denote something else

Comment: Error 2 A local variable named 'studentInfoClassAndNumber' cannot be declared in this scope because it would give a different meaning to 'studentInfoClassAndNumber', which is already used in a 'parent or current' scope to denote something else

Comment: i get those errors when i try to put the variables.

Comment: Did you make sure to remove the variable declarations from your if statement? you only need to declare them one time. If you wanted you can still reinitialize them just don't use the type i.e. variableName = new... not Type variableName = new...

Answer (score 0):

For starters, you need to place everything you currently have in the Main() method into an infinite while() loop. Be sure to add a condition to your if/else block that checks for option 3 "3. Exit from the program" so your user can quit.

Right now, it looks like your program allows the user to select 1 option, it executes that option, and then it exits (thereby losing the data between runs).

After you make this change, move the 
`List<string> studentInfoName = new List<string>();`
and
`List<int> studentInfoClassAndNumber = new List<int>();`
to just immediately follow
    `static void Main(string[] args)`

The result should look like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<string> studentInfoName = new List<string>();
            List<int> studentInfoClassAndNumber = new List<int>();
            while(true)
            {
                DrawStarLine();
                DrawTitle();
                DrawMenu();
                int answer = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                if (answer == 1)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Enter information about a student");
                    Console.Write("Name: ");
                    studentInfoName.Add(Console.ReadLine());
                    Console.Write("Middle name: ");
                    studentInfoName.Add(Console.ReadLine());
                    Console.Write("Last name: ");
                    studentInfoName.Add(Console.ReadLine());
                    Console.Write("Class ");
                    studentInfoClassAndNumber.Add(int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()));
                    Console.Write("Number ");
                    studentInfoClassAndNumber.Add(int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()));
                }
                else if (answer == 2)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Student Information");
                    foreach(String nextEntry in studentInfoName)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(nextEntry);
                    }

                    Console.WriteLine("Course Information");
                    foreach(String nextEntry in studentInfoClassAndNumber)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(nextEntry);
                    }

                }
                else if(answer == 3)
                {
                    return 0;
                else
                {
                    ErrorMessage();
                }
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }
        private static void ErrorMessage()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Typing error, press key to continue.");
        }
        private static void DrawStarLine()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("************************");
        }
        private static void DrawTitle()
        {
            DrawStarLine();
            Console.WriteLine("+++ Student Information Database +++");
            DrawStarLine();
        }
        private static void DrawMenu()
        {
            DrawStarLine();
            Console.WriteLine(" 1. Enter information about a student.");
            Console.WriteLine(" 2. Retrieve information about a student available in the program");
            Console.WriteLine(" 3. Exit from the program");
            DrawStarLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Make your choice: type 1, 2, or 3 for exit");
            DrawStarLine();
        }

        }
    }
```

A final note: your application (as it is programmed now) will only support one student. I would suggest using a Dictionary> to support multiple students. You can key each entry in the Dictionary by the student's name and store their information as a List (like you are already doing).

Best of luck,

Clinton

Comment: I seem to understand your answer better than the others. Thank you. I will do that and I will see how to use  Dictionary> to support multiple students. I will write again. :)